# Setting the background color of an NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to set a custom view (not the main one) with a custom NSColor background (`[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"]]`). I've tried making a custom view class:

.h

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface CustomBackground : NSView {
    NSColor *background; 
}
@property(retain) NSColor *background;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "CustomBackground.h"

@implementation CustomBackground
@synthesize background;

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [background set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}

- (void)changeColor:(NSColor*) aColor
{
    background = aColor;
    [aColor retain];
}
@end
```

And then in the AppDelegate:

```
[self.homeView changeColor:[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"]]];
```

But nothing happens, the color remains the same. What's wrong? Or is there an easier way? NSView doesn't have a `backgroundColor` property :(

Comment: this should be the best way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's best to use the already-made `setBackground:` method that you get from the `background` property. So replace your `changeColor:` method with:

```
-(void)setBackground:(NSColor *)aColor
{
    if([background isEqual:aColor]) return;
    [background release];
    background = [aColor retain];

    //This is the most crucial thing you're missing: make the view redraw itself
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

To change the color of your view, you can simply do:

```
self.homeView.background = [NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"]]
```

Comment: (1) Why check whether `background` is `nil`? If it is, the `release` message will do nothing. (2) Why assign `nil` to `background` immediately before assigning the new color?

Comment: NSView does not have a background property, not even a deprecated one... what am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
[self.homeView setWantsLayer:YES];
self.homeView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation as well.

Comment: This is the best solution to change the color with subclassing UIView and calling draw rect . Thanks,

Comment: This was a question about NSView (Cocoa) and not UIView (Cocoa Touch).  And is also not the best way to do it in a UIView.