# Setting background color in drawRect of NSSearchField subclass

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield, nssearchfield

I have a custom subclass of `NSSearchField` that I would like to set the background color of.

```
@interface CustomNSSearchField : NSSearchField
@end
```

So far, I have tried:

**Attempt #1**

```
@implementation CustomNSSearchField

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [self setDrawsBackground:YES];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor redColor]];
}
```

which resulted in no visual changes at all:

[image: attempt 1]

I then followed the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview) and also tried:

**Attempt #2**

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    [[NSColor redColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(rect);
}
```

Which results in this:

[image: attempt 2]

How do I set the background color *inside* the bounds and behind the text of the search field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to redraw the entire thing.
There is no property, to specifically change the background-color of the NSSearchField.
Check out this example:

[Custom NSSearchField](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/snrhudkit)

Edit:

Also what's worth to point out.
You should never override the controls drawRect method.
You should rather make a subclass of [NSSearchFieldCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSearchFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. Subclassing `NSSearchFieldCell` instead of `NSSearchField` fixed the problems.

Comment: @aam1r, could you post your working code? I'm trying to get something similar to work, but am not having very much luck.

Comment: @Zenox: I am sorry but I can't paste snippets of the codebase. What I would suggest though is looking at [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/). It's a library of commonly used UI elements. It is open-source and I had to go through the codebase to see how they were doing their customizations and followed a similar idea.

Comment: @Zenox What's your problem exactly? I'll try to help you out.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work for me. If anybody has working code, post it please.