# Is drawRect really changing the background color of a NSView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Everywhere on the internet I can read that to change the background color of a NSView you can just override its method drawRect like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    NSRectFill(rect);
}
```

For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview).

However, in my case, the color is drawn on top of the view (I can't see anymore the content), which is quite logical to me. DrawRect is supposed to draw the view, not just its background.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `[super drawRect:rect]` after filling the background. Otherwise, you're simply replacing everything that would be drawn by the superclass's implementation.

Comment: Assuming, of course, that there is a superclass (i.e., Patrick did not subclass NSView directly, but rather subclassed some other subclass of NSView).

Comment: If he had subclassed `NSView` directly, he wouldn't have observed the problem of disappearing content in the first place.

Comment: Docu says: "The default implementation does nothing. Subclasses should override this method if they do custom drawing. [...] If your custom view is a direct NSView subclass, you do not need to call super. For all other views, call super at some point in your implementation so that the parent class can perform any additional drawing."

Answer (score 0):

The examples you refer to are displaying the subviews of the view above the background.