# Setting Colour to an NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I am working on a Menubar app, which have a custom BackGroundView inherited from NSView, which is declared as a property named "backgroundView" in the PanelController class. I need to set violet color to this backgroundView. Can anybody tell me how do i accomplish this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You tagged your question with iOS. Aren't menubar apps & NSView OS X specific?

Comment: yes they are... I'm removing the tag; also [this same question has been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : Sorry, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

In your `drawRect:` method you would have something like:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:1 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1] set]; //Not sure if this is violet, just change the color yourself

    [NSBezierPath fillRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: But, when i use this, the color even fills the space between menubar and the View. I want only the background view to have the colour.