# Swift + NSViewController background color (Mac App)

Tags: swift, colors, background, nsviewcontroller

I am trying to change the background color of my View. The View Controller class is `NSViewController` type.

How this can be done? In iOS UIKit (`UIViewController`) there is `self.view.backgroundColor`, but `NSViewController` doesn't have that.

And second problem is how can I change the color of the applications Title Bar? I think the background color doesn't affect to that.

Mac application, language Swift. XCode 6.1.

Answer (score 55):

I managed to change background color of main view. NSViewController does not have backgroundColor property indeed, so I used the layer property of NSView that belongs to NSViewController. Here is the code.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.wantsLayer = true

    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if self.view.layer != nil {
            let color : CGColorRef = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = color
        }

    }
}
```

It will initialize the view controller with red background.

For Title Bar color, I created NSWindowController and assinged it to main window controller from storyboard. Here is the code.

```
class MainWindow: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        super.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Omg My eyes O_O

Answer (score 2):

Careful: calling setLayer: or setWantsLayer: breaks any WebViews you might have in your application in very creative ways! (Even in different windows...)

Please see this answer here [Best way to change the background color for an NSView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview/35790006#35790006).