# Changing background color of NSView in Swift 2.0

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I am trying to change the background color of NSView and have tried one of the solution outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26553444/swift-nsviewcontroller-background-color-mac-app). However, it's not working for me. What am I missing here? Should I use viewWillAppear() here or it only meant for iOS?

Related code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.wantsLayer = true

    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        if self.view.layer != nil {
            let color : CGColorRef = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1.0, 0, 0, 1.0)
            self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = color
        }

    }
}
```

P.S - I'm new to OS X/iOS programming and trying to figure my way out through documentation and existing solutions. Using Xcode 7 beta 4.

Comment: Your method also works for me using Xcode 7 beta 5

Comment: I think something got messed up in setting the initial controller. Thanks for your answer though. It works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).CGColor

    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: view.wantsLayer = true is the crucial point here. Seems starting some point CALayer is not automatically allocated for the view. Don't remember when it was introduced

Comment: another option is to change the window background color inside viewWillAppear