# How to change the disclosure button in NSSourceList?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, button, nsoutlineview

I´m trying to change the disclosure button in a NSSourceList. After a lot of research I found some suggestions written in objective-c.
I tried the solutions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127764/how-to-customize-disclosure-cell-in-view-based-nsoutlineview?rq=1) like this:

```
extension ViewController: NSOutlineViewDelegate {

    func outlineView(_ outlineView: NSOutlineView, willDisplayOutlineCell cell: Any, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, item: Any) {
        print("willDisplayOutlineCell")

    }
}
```

But this functions doesn´t get called. I also tried to set a custom disclosure button in Interface Builder.
Normally the result looks like this:

[image]

I put a custom button in the sourcelist like this:

[image]

But after that, the expansion doesn´t work anymore:

[image]

Would be really great to get some help.

Comment: NSSourceList doesn't exist, do you mean NSOutlineView?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you customise the groupItem-look in a view-based NSOutlineView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716670/how-do-you-customise-the-groupitem-look-in-a-view-based-nsoutlineview/44047591#44047591)