# NSColorWell for View Background | Swift OSx

Tags: swift, macos, nscolorwell

Currently I can change the background color of my window like so:

```
tab_view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1).CGColor
```

Which is great and all, but I want the user to be able to change the color.
This is when I found out about NSColorWell.

I tried applying the color like so:

```
tab_view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColorWell
```

but then it says "Can't assign value of type 'NSColorWell.Type' to type 'CGColor'?"
I tried looking it up, but everything I found (which was barely any) was written in Objective - C

Someone please explain to me how I can make the view background color a color from the NSColorWell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass NSColorWell .color .CGColor property value. [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorWell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSColorWell/color)

Comment: I typed it like this but it is not working still.
`tab_view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColorWell().color.CGColor`

Comment: This is not actual code. You need to pass `yourNSColorWell.color.CGColor` check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31214482/2303865 you need to set wantsLayer = true