# osx: I set one subview alpha, but all its super views be alpha?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I write a window and two subviews, the drawRect of top subview is like:

```
[[[NSColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] set];
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(100, 100, 200, 200));
```

and the bottom subview is a image view.
But when I run, I found all the views and window be alpha, the top subview will show the desktop with the color.

Anybody knows the reason? Thanks for the help.

---

The structure of my code is like this:
windowController includes: window and viewcontroller.
viewcontroller includes view1 and view2.
view1 is a imageview.
view2 I write nothing, just override the drawRect with the codes before.

I had wrote these before,but did not meet this problem, so I am really confused.

When I check the view UI hierarchy, I found it is correct.

---

I reproduced this problem in my test project, this is my test project:

In appDelegate

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
TestViewController *controller = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.window.frame.size.width, self.window.frame.size.height)];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blueColor]];
[self.window setContentView:controller.view];
```

}

In TestViewController

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    TestView *view = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.view = view;
}
return self;
```

}

In TestView

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
[super drawRect:dirtyRect];

// Drawing code here.
[[[NSColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] set];
NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
```

}

And in view UI hierarchy:
 [image]

And run
[image]

finally, it only red color, but the backgroundcolor of window is blue.

Comment: "I found all the views and window be alpha"  That's not English.  What does that mean?

Comment: Have you set the background color of the window? If so, to what? Does your view incorrectly return `YES` from an override of `-isOpaque`? Are you using vibrancy? Can you reproduce the problem with a new project with just this custom view?

Comment: @ElTomato sorry for my poor english, I means the top view shows the desktop directly, without the bottom imageview.

Comment: @KenThomases Yes, I reproduce it. But I still not know why. I will post my source code in my question. Thanks for help.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the whole `drawRect` method from your view implementation? Does it show the blue background then?

Comment: @kender Yes, if I comment out the drawRect, it runs right.

Comment: And why don't you just set the background color of your view, instead of drawing on it on the lower level? Like it's shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27954805/4172

Comment: I divide it in two subViews, because in my project the viewController should manages four subviews, and these subviews are for different function. And really, I want to know what's the reason. I think there must be some knowledge I did not know before.

Answer (score 0):

I change the

```
NSRectFill
```

to

```
NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeSourceOver);
```

Then it turns right.