# How to change background color of Custom NSView with a custom color

Tags: swift, nsview, nsviewcontroller

Hey so i am trying to chnage background of my NSView to a custom color.
i looked up a lot of examples and followed them and still didnt exactly achive what i was looking for, So i want to change the bacground color but for somereason it dosent work. here is the code : - 
    import Cocoa

```
class GoalsVC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var topView: NSView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
    }
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        topView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedRed: 109, green: 188, blue: 99, alpha: 1).cgColor
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

So,line no 3 was supposed to work since if i do this it works :-

```
topView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue.cgColor
```

So, i might be making a stupid mistake just help me out here. ThankYou

Comment: Have you read the documentation for that `NSColor` init method? *"Values below 0.0 are interpreted as 0.0, and values above 1.0 are interpreted as 1.0."*.

Comment: You should set `wantsLayer` using `topView` instead of `view`

Comment: @rmaddy So how do you suggest i do this because as you said all my numbers are considerd 1.0 right ? thanks for taking the time to response

Comment: Review the answers in the question I used to close your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview/31214482?s=1|0.0000#31214482

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks yah i though i should do that but that does not seem to solve the problem

Comment: @HozaifaOwaisi check the link above. As @rmaddy already mentioned `NSColor(calibratedRed: 109/255, green: 188/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 1)`

Comment: ok i got it thanks @LeoDabus