How to change background color of xamarin.mac app?
I have basic xamarin.mac app and I don't know how to change his background color.
// viewcontroller.cs (c#)

using System;

using AppKit;
using Foundation;

namespace Application
{
    public partial class ViewController : NSViewController
    {
        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            labelOnChange.StringValue = "";
            textFieldOnChange.Changed += LabelChanged;
        }

        public override NSObject RepresentedObject {
            get {
                return base.RepresentedObject;
            }
            set {
                base.RepresentedObject = value;
                // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }

        void LabelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get the new value
            labelOnChange.StringValue = textFieldOnChange.StringValue;
        }

        partial void buttonClear(NSObject sender)
        {
            textFieldOnChange.StringValue = "";
            labelOnChange.StringValue = "";
        }
    }
}

Is there simple label which can change bg color, like in Xcode interface builder or I have to write it yourself in viewcontroller.cs (in VS)?
I was try to find NSWindow object which have relation to my project, and to use his backgroundcolor method, but I didn't find him

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview. As you are working with the Cocoa views, then the same approaches are fully valid for the Xamarin. Just translate the code into C# (or just click the same buttons in the XCode if you prefer the no-code solution)

Just add
public override void ViewWillAppear()
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear();

            this.View.Window.BackgroundColor = NSColor.FromRgb(84, 161, 184);
        }

to your viewcontroller.cs file.
You also can use FromRgba() if you wanna add alpha channel
